# How to get functions to not evaluate the return until the end

Tags: vb.net, function, return

I have functions in my program that stop after it reaches a Return line but I need the function to continue in case what I want the function to return changes.

Is there a workaround for this or a way to force the function to continue after a return?

I made a Test Program to demonstrate the problem. It is a Form that contains only a button.

Here is the source code:

```
Private Sub btnTest_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnTest.Click
    If testFunction() = True Then
        MsgBox("It returned True!")
    Else
        MsgBox("It returned False!")
    End If
End Sub

Function testFunction() As Boolean
    Dim testVariable As Boolean = True
    Return False
    If testVariable = True Then
        Return True
    End If
End Function
```

The messagebox always says "It returned False" when if it continued going through the code like I want it to it would have returned true.

Comment: in testFunction() function after declaring testVariable  variable u returned false .that's y its returning false always.u have to change that sequence

Comment: You misunderstand my problem. I did that on purpose. I wanted a way for it to keep going after `Return False`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have a flag variable set up, so use it!

```
Function testFunction() As Boolean
    Dim testVariable As Boolean = True
    testVariable = False

    Return testVariable
End Function
```

Also, don't *ever* use `= True` or `= False` in comparisons. `= True` is 100% redundant and `x = False` should be `Not x`.

---

**EDIT:** Sorry, that wasn't clear.

```
If x = True Then
    ' ...
End If
```

is always<sup>*</sup> the same as

```
If x Then
    ' ...
End If
```

Comment: No, my problem was simply that I want the code to continue after the return line. The the only reason that variable was there was to demonstrate that the code didn't continue after the first return line. Also, if I'm not supposed to use `= True` or `= False` then what am I supposed to use?

Comment: @MarkKramer: Okay... so make another flag. The point of `Return` is that (you guessed it!) it returns from the function. As for what to replace `= True` with... nothing! Take it out and watch your code run free.

Comment: So when you declare a Boolean Variable it is true by default?

Comment: Oh okay. Well, is there any real reason to use `x` and `Not x` in place of `x = True` and `x = False`? Does it make the code more efficient or is it just your personal preference?

Comment: @MarkKramer: Well, there's definitely a reason not to use `x = True`. The compiler can sometimes optimize it out, but it makes for slightly messier code. And you really run into problems when the operator `=` is overloaded for the class with a `Boolean`. Nobody should ever, ever do that, but still... as for `Not x`, it's not quite as important, but it is shorter and implies your intent a little better IMO. Also for the operator overloading reason, of course.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub btnTest_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnTest.Click
    If testFunction() Then
        MsgBox("It returned True!")
    Else
        MsgBox("It returned False!")
    End If
End Sub  

Function testFunction() As Boolean
  Dim testVariable As Boolean = True
    If testVariable Then
        Return True
    End If
    Return False
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do:

```
Function testFunction() As Boolean
  Dim testVariable As Boolean = True
  Return testVariable
End Function
```

Since testVariable is a boolean and the return type is boolean.